# Burninate [notes]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag [notes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notes) is attached to six Open Qs at present:

[What does tagging a note with a page in Facebook do?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/what-does-tagging-a-note-with-a-page-in-facebook-do)

[Multiple pages in a single note in Evernote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/multiple-pages-in-a-single-note-in-evernote)

[How to schedule a draft note on a Facebook page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/how-to-schedule-a-draft-note-on-a-facebook-page)

[Tumblr wrong note count](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20289/tumblr-wrong-note-count)

<strike>[Attach a note to an email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/attach-a-note-to-an-email-in-gmail)</strike>

[How do you post a Facebook Note in a group or on a page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41391/how-do-you-post-a-facebook-note-in-a-group-or-on-a-page)

[Does Google Docs have these features?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/does-google-docs-have-these-features)

Where there seems to be a mixture of application specific meanings and vernacular usage.

The tag has three followers and no Usage guide. In no case is it the only tag. There are a further eight Closed Qs so tagged, a proportion that may serve as a warning of problems. IMO the As to Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

> - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
> - Is it unambiguous?
> - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

are, in order: No, No, Depends, No, No.

There is already a tag with a Usage guide [annotations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/annotations) (four Open Qs):

> Annotations are typically used to point out, or explain a specific portion of content, such as in YouTube videos.

which would seem adequate to cover the vernacular usage, if required. The jargon usage (eg Evernote, Tumblr) might also be confused with other applications such as OneNote.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no more questions tagged [notes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notes). The tag itself will be cleaned up within 24 hours.